# Germany Einreiseanmeldung "Travel Details": which flight number?

Tags: paperwork, germany, covid-19

We are (hopefully) flying BOS->IAD->BRU->BER tomorrow (don't ask) with Berlin as the final destination. I'm filling out the German travel registration (Eineiseanmeldung) which in the section "Travel Details" asks about the flight number. I have three to choose from.

Covid testing is required. PCR test must be done no more than 48 hours before boarding the first leg, Antigen must be taken no more than 48 hours before the arrival in Germany. So by this argument I could either choose BOS-IAD or BRU->BER. They do have an extra field for "stop overs", which is also unclear. Do they mean layovers (i.e. a connecting flight) or real stopovers (which typically means more than 24 hours with luggage unloaded and re-check required).

Any hints would be appreciated.

Quick update: I looked at the German version of the form and there "stopover" is called "Umstieg" which I believe is more like "layover".

Comment: Is there a data field (or opportunity) to include or attach supplementary information?

Comment: I'm not sure about the reasons for the flight number, but I suspect it might have to do with covid tracking in case a passenger tests positive. I filled out an Einreiseanmeldung a month ago, but can't remember if they also asked for seat information. Norway entry had a similar system and they requested final flight number + seating, and additional connecting airports. The connecting airport in that case should then be provided even if its a 10 minute change of aircraft

Comment: The stopover field of your arrival details are meant to include layovers as far as I am aware. It is optional and does not trigger anything if you fill it in. In fact, you only get there *after* selecting the countries you passed through.

Answer (score 1):

The BRU->**BER** flight number would be the first disembarkation point in Germany.

> [FAQ Coronavirus Entry Regulations - Bundesgesundheitsministerium](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/en/coronavirus/infos-reisende/faq-tests-einreisende.html#c20266):
> **At what point in time am I entering Germany?**
> *If entry into Germany is through a carrier, entry is determined to be the **first scheduled disembarkation point** in the Federal Republic of Germany.*

That would be the flight number used where the time of entry into Germany is decisive (i.e. non-PCR tests).

Comment: If "flight into Germany" is all they wanted, why would they add "stopovers" to the form ?

Comment: To determin, if during your trip, you were in an  *high-risk area or area of variants of concern*. Whereby *connection times at an airport are **not** deemed to constitute a stopover*. Had you stayed a longer period, visiting the city before continuing your trip, that would be considered at stopover.

Comment: It seems like there is mismatch between the English and the German version. English is "stopover" which would be "Zwischenstopp" in German. German says "Umstieg" which would be a "layover" in English. I went with the first leg BOS->IAD since we did a PCR test.  We'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after the trip.

I used the first leg of the trip (BOS->IAD) adding Washington and Brussels in the "stopover" field. That worked fine. Chances are that just using the last leg would have worked as well but I have no data support this one way or another.